# radeon 0000:01:00.0: failed VCE resume (-110)

Tags: radeon

Today I installed the latest version of Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. When my installation is completed then Getting message for restart computer. Now I am getting error message after restarted the computer. It shows radeon 0000:01:00.0: failed VCE resume (-110), No cache mode page found and Assuming drive cache write through. Screen remains ​black with this error message forever. Please let me know that How we can fixing this issue?

[​black with this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPH8O.jpg)